# Video Chat working but no sound in call Agora.io

Tags: java, android-studio, audio-streaming, agora.io, videocall

I am creating Video Call Activity, everything was ok until yesterday. Today I continued developing the app and noticed that there is no sound in video calls, the video calls is working but the sound is missing.

1. I am using Agora.io SDK;
2. The only thing that I did is that I switched the project to a new one, and updated the project ID with the new ID that I got from Agora Dashboard in `strings.xml`;
3. I even created a new account in Agore Site, and created a new project there, then added the new app ID, but still able to make video calls without sound;
4. I checked the application permissions in settings, and it was: phone, camera, microphone, storage.

Permissions declared in the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

```
    package sixstrings.guitar.boc;

    import android.Manifest;
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import io.agora.rtc.Constants;
    import io.agora.rtc.IRtcEngineEventHandler;
    import io.agora.rtc.RtcEngine;
    import io.agora.rtc.video.VideoEncoderConfiguration;
    import io.agora.rtc.video.VideoCanvas;

    public class VideoCall extends AppCompatActivity {

        private RtcEngine mRtcEngine;

        // Permissions
        private static final int PERMISSION_REQ_ID = 22;
        private static final String[] REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

        private static final String LOG_TAG = VideoCall.class.getSimpleName();

        // Handle SDK Events
        private final IRtcEngineEventHandler mRtcEventHandler = new IRtcEngineEventHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFirstRemoteVideoDecoded(final int uid, int width, int height, int elapsed) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // set first remote user to the main bg video container
                        setupRemoteVideoStream(uid);
                    }
                });


            }

            // remote user has left channel
            @Override
            public void onUserOffline(int uid, int reason) { // Tutorial Step 7
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onRemoteUserLeft();
                    }
                });
            }

            // remote user has toggled their video
            @Override
            public void onUserMuteVideo(final int uid, final boolean toggle) { // Tutorial Step 10
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        onRemoteUserVideoToggle(uid, toggle);
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.video_call_test);

            if (checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[0], PERMISSION_REQ_ID) &&
                    checkSelfPermission(REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS[1], PERMISSION_REQ_ID)) {
                initAgoraEngine();
            }

            findViewById(R.id.audioBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE); // set the audio button hidden
            findViewById(R.id.leaveBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE); // set the leave button hidden
            findViewById(R.id.videoBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE); // set the video button hidden
        }

        private void initAgoraEngine() {
            try {
                mRtcEngine = RtcEngine.create(getBaseContext(), getString(R.string.agora_app_id), mRtcEventHandler);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));

                throw new RuntimeException("NEED TO check rtc sdk init fatal error\n" + Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            setupSession();
        }

        private void setupSession() {
            mRtcEngine.setChannelProfile(Constants.CHANNEL_PROFILE_COMMUNICATION);

            mRtcEngine.enableVideo();

            mRtcEngine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(new VideoEncoderConfiguration(VideoEncoderConfiguration.VD_640x480, VideoEncoderConfiguration.FRAME_RATE.FRAME_RATE_FPS_30,
                    VideoEncoderConfiguration.STANDARD_BITRATE,
                    VideoEncoderConfiguration.ORIENTATION_MODE.ORIENTATION_MODE_FIXED_PORTRAIT));
        }

        private void setupLocalVideoFeed() {

            // setup the container for the local user
            FrameLayout videoContainer = findViewById(R.id.floating_video_container);


            SurfaceView videoSurface = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
            videoSurface.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
            videoContainer.addView(videoSurface);
            mRtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(new VideoCanvas(videoSurface, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT,0));
        }

        private void setupRemoteVideoStream(int uid) {
            // setup ui element for the remote stream

            FrameLayout videoContainer = findViewById(R.id.bg_video_container);
            FrameLayout videoContainer2 = findViewById(R.id.floating_video_container2);
            FrameLayout videoContainer3 = findViewById(R.id.floating_video_container3);
            FrameLayout videoContainer4 = findViewById(R.id.floating_video_container4);
            // ignore any new streams that join the session
            if (videoContainer.getChildCount() >= 4) {
                return;
            }

            SurfaceView videoSurface = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
            SurfaceView videoSurface2 = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
            SurfaceView videoSurface3 = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());
            SurfaceView videoSurface4 = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(getBaseContext());

            videoContainer.addView(videoSurface);
            videoContainer2.addView(videoSurface2);
            videoContainer3.addView(videoSurface3);
            videoContainer4.addView(videoSurface4);


            mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(new VideoCanvas(videoSurface, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, uid));
            mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(new VideoCanvas(videoSurface2, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, uid));
            mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(new VideoCanvas(videoSurface3, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, uid));
            mRtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(new VideoCanvas(videoSurface4, VideoCanvas.RENDER_MODE_FIT, uid));
            mRtcEngine.setRemoteSubscribeFallbackOption(io.agora.rtc.Constants.STREAM_FALLBACK_OPTION_AUDIO_ONLY);

        }

        public void onAudioMuteClicked(View view) {
            ImageView btn = (ImageView) view;
            if (btn.isSelected()) {
                btn.setSelected(false);
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mic_black_24dp);
            } else {
                btn.setSelected(true);
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mic_off_black_24dp);
            }

            mRtcEngine.muteLocalAudioStream(btn.isSelected());
        }

        public void onVideoMuteClicked(View view) {
            ImageView btn = (ImageView) view;
            if (btn.isSelected()) {
                btn.setSelected(false);
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_videocam_red_24dp);
            } else {
                btn.setSelected(true);
                btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_videocam_off_black_24dp);
            }

            mRtcEngine.muteLocalVideoStream(btn.isSelected());

            FrameLayout container = findViewById(R.id.floating_video_container);
            FrameLayout container2 = findViewById(R.id.floating_video_container2);
            FrameLayout container3 = findViewById(R.id.floating_video_container3);
            FrameLayout container4 = findViewById(R.id.floating_video_container4);

            container.setVisibility(btn.isSelected() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            container2.setVisibility(btn.isSelected() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            container3.setVisibility(btn.isSelected() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            container4.setVisibility(btn.isSelected() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

            SurfaceView videoSurface = (SurfaceView) container.getChildAt(0);
            videoSurface.setZOrderMediaOverlay(!btn.isSelected());
            videoSurface.setVisibility(btn.isSelected() ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }

        // join the channel when user clicks UI button
        public void onjoinChannelClicked(View view) {
            mRtcEngine.joinChannel(null, "test-channel", "Extra Optional Data", 0); // if you do not specify the uid, Agora will assign one.
            setupLocalVideoFeed();
            findViewById(R.id.joinBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE); // set the join button hidden
            findViewById(R.id.audioBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // set the audio button hidden
            findViewById(R.id.leaveBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // set the leave button hidden
            findViewById(R.id.videoBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // set the video button hidden
        }

        public void onLeaveChannelClicked(View view) {
            leaveChannel();
            removeVideo(R.id.floating_video_container);
            removeVideo(R.id.floating_video_container2);
            removeVideo(R.id.floating_video_container4);
            removeVideo(R.id.floating_video_container3);

            removeVideo(R.id.bg_video_container);
            findViewById(R.id.joinBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // set the join button visible
            findViewById(R.id.audioBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE); // set the audio button hidden
            findViewById(R.id.leaveBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE); // set the leave button hidden
            findViewById(R.id.videoBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE); // set the video button hidden
        }

        private void leaveChannel() {
            mRtcEngine.leaveChannel();
        }

        private void removeVideo(int containerID) {
            FrameLayout videoContainer = findViewById(containerID);
            videoContainer.removeAllViews();
        }

        private void onRemoteUserVideoToggle(int uid, boolean toggle) {
            FrameLayout videoContainer = findViewById(R.id.bg_video_container);

            SurfaceView videoSurface = (SurfaceView) videoContainer.getChildAt(0);
            videoSurface.setVisibility(toggle ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

            // add an icon to let the other user know remote video has been disabled
            if(toggle){
                ImageView noCamera = new ImageView(this);
                noCamera.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_disabled);
                videoContainer.addView(noCamera);
            } else {
                ImageView noCamera = (ImageView) videoContainer.getChildAt(1);
                if(noCamera != null) {
                    videoContainer.removeView(noCamera);
                }
            }
        }

        private void onRemoteUserLeft() {
            removeVideo(R.id.bg_video_container);
        }



        public boolean checkSelfPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "checkSelfPermission " + permission + " " + requestCode);
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        REQUESTED_PERMISSIONS,
                        requestCode);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult " + grantResults[0] + " " + requestCode);

            switch (requestCode) {
                case PERMISSION_REQ_ID: {
                    if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || grantResults[1] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Need permissions " + Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO + "/" + Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                        break;
                    }

                    initAgoraEngine();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            leaveChannel();
            RtcEngine.destroy();
            mRtcEngine = null;
        }

        public final void showLongToast(final String msg) {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }


    }
```

```
    <resources>
        <string name="agora_app_id">xxasldfsidfshjdfskdsfsl</string>
        <string name="app_name">6 STRINGS   </string>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Does everything work when you use your app id in the following website: https://sidsharma27.github.io? Also, is the issue with your local or remote audio? Meaning, is your local audio not being transmitted or are you not able to hear the remote audio?

Comment: thanks for your help , looks like the issue with my phone , for no reason my phone does not send sound unitl i did removed the app , re installed , added permissions manually , then it work ONLY in use with 2nd person , but , if you open the app and waiting for the other person to connect it doesnt shows any thing , but it works on another phones perfectly .i think i need to close this post , but this comment wont work as an answer so i will keep it open >

Comment: Looks like you're having a device specific issue. In that case, I would recommend you to go through agora's support channel and get help from there. You can file your ticket here: https://agora-ticket.agora.io/

Comment: thanks, I opened a ticket using the link that you provided.